# Matplotlib change bar color

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib changes the color of the bar when there are more values plotted : 
With 5 columns I get the expected red bars :

```
ax = vc[vc.index[:5]].plot(color='red', kind='bar', title=col+('(count)'))

    ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

[image: Expected red bars]

But going for more values, the colors begin to fade and there is some grey bars appearing :(

```
ax = vc.plot(color='red', kind='bar', title=col+('(count)'))
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

[image: Bar color change]

How can I keep My red bars all along ?

Answer (score 0):

They probably become gray because of the edge colors of the bars:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import pandas as p

pl.figure()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.random(x.size)
vc1 = p.DataFrame(data=y, index=x)

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.random(x.size)
vc2 = p.DataFrame(data=y, index=x)

ax = pl.subplot(131)
vc1.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')

ax = pl.subplot(132)
vc2.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')

ax = pl.subplot(133)
vc2.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red', edgecolor='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice point !Your third graph is tile becoming light-red. Is there a way to have a full red all the way long ?

Comment: If you look at the full sized image, all bars are "full" red, only some bars are 1 pixel wide, and some are 2 pixels wide. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: If your number of bars is approaching your number of pixel you should probably switch to using `ax.step`

Comment: or `fill_between` with the `step` kwarg (new in 1.5)

Comment: This is the anti-aliasing biting you, you could also adjust the bar parameters not have a gap between the bars.